# Python Nose tests from generator not running concurrently

Tags: python, nose

Given the following:

```
from time import sleep

def runTest(a):
    sleep(1)
    assert a >= 0

def test_all():
    for i in range(5):
        yield (runTest, i)
```

I would expect the five tests to get run in parallel running with `nosetests --processes=8` and thus run in approximately one second — however, it takes just over five seconds to run: they appear to be running sequentially and not concurrently.

According to the nose documentation, the multiprocess plugin has supported test generators (as the nose documentation calls them) since 1.1: I'm using nose 1.3.0 so it should be supported. Adding `_multiprocess_can_split_ = True` does make any difference, as one would expect, as fixtures are not used.

How do I get these five tests to run concurrently?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to nose's author, [on the mailing list](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/nose-users/PHcGXlGQZMg/XKgUsDcyf7cJ), the multiprocess plugin does not work with generators in 1.3 ([a known bug](https://github.com/nose-devs/nose/issues/499)), and he recommends sticking with 1.1 if one needs it to work.

Answer (score 3):

You may try

```
from time import sleep
from multiprocessing import Process

def runTest(a):
    sleep(1)
    assert a >= 0

def test_all():
    for i in range(5):
        Process(target=(yield (runTest, i))).start()
```

Comment: I'd much rather understand why nose's multiprocess plugin isn't managing to run the existing tests concurrently rather than parallelize them externally to nose.

Comment: I don't know what settings you are using but this solution does not work at all. All tests are run on the same process and are run sequentially. This was done on nose 1.3 using various combinations of multiprocess variables and nosetests commands. The problems seems to originate using yield.